# Firebase does not support mac os

Tags: flutter, firebase, macos

I am developing an app with flutter. I plan to support Android, iOS, macOS, and windows.
But I found that Firebase doesn't work for mac os.

In flutterfire, I chose the following platforms:
✔ Which platforms should your configuration support (use arrow keys & space to select)? · android, ios, macos

But when I ran flutter build -d macos, I got the error “DefaultFirebaseOptions have not been configured for macos”.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to add this code inside your void main(), just after `WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();`

```html
 await Firebase.initializeApp(
      options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
    );
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to give your MacOS app Internet access by adding the following to your `DebugProfile.entitlements` file and `Release.entitlements` file in your `macOS/Runner` directory:

```
<key>com.apple.security.network.client</key>
<true/>
```

I can't tell you how long it took me to figure this out.

Comment: thanks a lot! I had no idea why await like " await db.collection("users").add(user)" didn't return result/control, in case running the app on OS X.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting up firebase for macOS using the non flutter fire method - manually downloading a configuration file when you add the macOS app on firebase and including that in your XcodeWorkSpace file.

https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/manual-installation/macos/

Answer (score 0):

You need to add:

```
<key>com.apple.security.network.client</key>
<true/>
```

to `macos/Runner/DebugProfile.entitlements` and `macos/Runner/Release.entitlements`.